# Invoke save as dialog on window.location pointed to image file

Tags: javascript

I have this line of javascript to open an imagedata on a page

```
window.location.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

How can I make it invoke the `save as dialog / download image` so that the visitor can save the image immediately after image load?

Currently user needs to `right click>save image as` to save the image. It would be nice to automatically invoke save as dialog.

I found this that might work
[downloading file with save as dialog box in jsp...how to prompt user for save,view cancel dialog instead of directly opening image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318365/downloading-file-with-save-as-dialog-box-in-jsp-how-to-prompt-user-for-save-vi)

But I don't know how to add `response.setheader` after the page/image loads. I tried this

```
window.location.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + <?php the_title(); ?> + '.jpg');
```

But it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/386863/2888561

Comment: Thanks. That is what I am trying to do but my page is generated by the canvas |  canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');  |. It's not an actual page where I can hard code the header. Hence I need a means to inject the header using js or php way.

Answer (score 0):

You can you [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) attribute of `a` element for that. It causes the anchor element to invoke download dialog instead of loading targeted content in browser. Currently it's not supported by IE and Safari according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download).

Following example shows in-place creation of temporary hidden `a` element. Download dialog is activated using `click()` method.

```js
var url = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'file-name.png';
  a.style = 'display: none';
  button.parentNode.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  a.remove();
});
```

```html
<button>download</button>
```